# I'm stuck in this code

Tags: java

I just start learning java. I coppied this code from the book. But it cant run. Please help me out!!

```
public class Player {
    int number = 0; // where the guess game goes
    public void guess() {
        number = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        System.out.println("I'm guessing " + number);
    }
}

public class GameLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GuessGame game = new GuessGame();
        game.startGame();
    }
}
```

Above this snippets of codes i declared another class named GuessGame. But when i compiled, it said "Class Player/GamLauncher is public, should be declared in a file named Player.java/GameLauncher.java"

Comment: keep the `GameLauncher` class public, not both classes public.

Comment: Those snippets are designed to be separate files, not one file.

Comment: That's right! bro @cricket_007

Answer (score 3):

The problem is exactly what the compiler says the problem is! You can't put two top-level public classes in one file(Thanks to @rdonuk for reminding me that this only applies to top-level classes). There are two solutions:
1. Make the `Player` class not-`public` (`(default)`, `private`, or `protected`).
2. Put the `Player` class in a file called `Player.java` and the `GameLauncher` class in a file called `GameLauncher.java`.

Comment: Two public classes can be declared in one file, if they are not top level classes.

Comment: Right. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: OP probably forgot to paste the brace here, as otherwise the file wouldn't compile at all (he says he compiled it, and even posts the message he got)

Comment: Okay. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks to @AlexL'comment. I've handled the problem!